# I can't access a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, forms, insert

I have a form to user registry. Form send dates to InsertUser.php, which is the next file:

```
<?php 
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$link) {
    echo("ERROR");
}
else {
    if (!mysql_select_db("myfacebook", $link)) {
        echo("ERROR");
    }
    else {
        $Consulta = "insert into usuarios(Nombre,Apellidos,Nick,Contraseña,Foto) values('" . $_POST["nombre"] . "','" . $_POST["apellidos"] . "','" . $_POST["nick"] . "','" . $_POST["contraseña"] . "','PruebaFoto')";
        echo $Consulta;
        $resultado = mysql_query($Consulta, $link) or die("Problema al insertar los datos.");
        echo($resultado);
    }
} 
?>
```

When I sending and insert data, the form returns:

> "Problema al insertar los datos."

I think that function `mysql_query()` is the problem, but I don't know repair the problem.

Comment: Sql injection is the name of that query.Are you sure column type and variable type match and they are not empty?

Comment: `echo mysql_error($link);` after `mysql_query()` to get exact error message. remove `die()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's clean this up a bit and make it a little easier to see what's going on

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("myfacebook", $link) or die(mysql_error());

$Consulta = "insert into usuarios(Nombre,Apellidos,Nick,Contraseña,Foto) values('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["nombre"])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["apellidos"])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["nick"])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["contraseña"])."','PruebaFoto')";

if($sql = mysql_query($Consulta)) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

You need to escape your input so you're not open to SQL injection. I used `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

You should learn `mysqli` or `POD` instead of `mysql`.

I used `die()` in my example just to keep things clean and easy to understand.

Comment: It doesn't work. I think that it's an error caused by the table because other queries to the same table return a error.

Comment: What's the error message you're receiving? Also, make sure you're not using any reserved words in your field names: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: The error message is "error" and it occurs in the same place, in "mysql_query". I'm not using any reserved words and also I don't try to insert a repeated file.

Comment: what is the error from mysql? use mysql_error() instead of your own error. $sql = mysql_query($Consulta) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: It's solve! It had a error with "ñ" of "Contraseña".  Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! Please mark my answer as 'answered' by clicking the check image, so other people will know how it was solved and they won't answer it in the future. Glad I could help. :)